# use VPageBreaks on Every sheet of WorkBook using Macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I am trying to Drag page-break in the sheets present in workbook using Macro VBA , below is code.

```
Sub removepagebreak()
Dim i As Long
Dim sn As String

Dim sb As Worksheet
For Each sb In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

 i = sb.VPageBreaks.Count
 sn = sb.Name
 
 ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
 If i = "0" Then
 Else
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sn).Activate
 ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1

 End If
    
 Next sb

 For Each w In Application.Workbooks
    w.Save
Next w



End Sub
```

this code is working good when i put on Workbook, but if i try to import this using VB.net then i showing error.
Code of VB.net is here

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim PBXL As Excel.Application
        Dim PBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim PSheet As Excel.Worksheet
 
        PBXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
        PBook = PBXL.Workbooks.Open("D:\MCROPDF\abc Invoice Summary 2021-4.xlsx")
        PBXL.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import("D:\MCROPDF\RemovePageBreak.bas")


        PBXL.Run("removepagebreak")
        PBook.Save()
        PBook.Close(True)
        PBXL.DisplayAlerts = False
 
        PBXL.UserControl = False
        PSheet = Nothing
        PBook = Nothing
        PBXL = Nothing
    End Sub
```

after running from this above code, then error come on this line

```
 ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
```

i think  using macro from vb.net can't identify the active sheets.

Please tell me what should i do

Error in macro
[image]

Error in VB.net
[image]

Code of VBA  in VB.net

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim xlApplication As Excel.Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Dim xlWorkbooks As Excel.Workbooks
        Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim i As String
        xlWorkbooks = xlApplication.Workbooks
        xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open("D:\MCROPDF\Neuro Center Invoice Summary 2021-4.xlsx")
       
        xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        i = xlWorksheet.VPageBreaks.Count
        If i = 1 Then
            xlApplication.ActiveWindow.View = Excel.XlWindowView.xlPageBreakPreview

            xlWorksheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff(Direction:=Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1)

        End If
         
        xlApplication.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import("D:\MCROPDF\ExcelToPDF.bas")

        xlApplication.Run("printtopdf")
        xlWorkbook.Save()
        xlWorkbook.Close(True)
        xlApplication.DisplayAlerts = False

        xlApplication.UserControl = False
        xlWorksheet = Nothing
        xlWorkbook = Nothing
        xlApplication = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: `PSheet = PBook.Worksheets(1)`  then `PSheet.VPageBreaks(1) etc...` ?

Comment: @braX i already used this, but same error is coming.

Comment: @braX please check, i attached the error screenshot.

Comment: Side comment: while it works in VBA, it's not a good habit to test if an integer value is equal to a string representation of another integer value. Just test `i = 0`.

Comment: Try using `PSheet.Activate` in your .NET code after you set the value of `PSheet` correctly.

Comment: then what should i do, i want to remove the page break in the whole excel document and then print to pdf. and reason to remove page break is while printing to pdf those sheet having page break there data come to next page. so please suggest what should i do in this condtion

Comment: Side comment (2): it's rather silly to import a VBA module to an Excel sheet on the fly, just to run some VBA. You should be able to achieve the same from VB.NET with COM.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes u r right, but problem is i have 100 of excels and i have to use this dynamically. my macro is working good when i used it on excel, but its shows error while importing from vb.net only. is there any other things from where i can put macro in diiferent excel on a single click.

Comment: Have you tried [Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.resetallpagebreaks)? Regarding this macro, as I said, you should be able to do the same in pure VB.NET with a COM client controlling Excel. I don't know the syntax in VB.NET, but I have done this many times with Python's [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) module. You shouldn't add a macro to an Excel file just for this.

Comment: I was also confused at why you were using both VBA and .NET. There is probably a better solution for all of this rather than doing it the way you are trying to.

Comment: yes i tired  Worksheet.ResetAllPageBreaks. but nothing work. i added some more code in above. can u please look at there. i tried many approaches, but nothing works.

Comment: @braX  i have 100 of excels and  i have to export all excel sheet to pdf. and those excel sheet having page break due to which while exporting pdf there columns comes to next page. due to this i made macro to remove page break in all excel first then print to pdf.

Comment: All of which can be done using .NET instead of VBA.

Comment: ...and it doesn't matter how many "Excels" you have either... you just use a loop and go thru them one by one.